How to check etcd contents from filesystem backup
I was provided a filesystem backup from a docker volume backing an etcd instance. The file system contents are arranged as below:
122M    ./_data/member/wal
 96K    ./_data/member/snap
122M    ./_data/member
366M    ./_data/datav3/member/wal
3.4G    ./_data/datav3/member/snap
3.8G    ./_data/datav3/member
3.8G    ./_data/datav3
3.9G    ./_data

I put these files to my laptop and fired up etcd using --data-dir pointing to the path of _data above.
etcd --data-dir etcd/_data
etcd comes up and I seem to be able to connect with it using etcdctl. Like this works (sorta):
√ ~ %>> etcdctl get --keys-only -w json /
{"header":{"cluster_id":14841639068965178418,"member_id":10276657743932975437,"revision":4,"raft_term":4}}

But I am not able to see any of the old data. I can push new data using put commands though. Should I be able to view like this or do I need to get a snapshot, do a restore etc?
Ultimately I want to find out the contents, which are the key-values that are hogging up space within etcd.
